# php duplicates output

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I use this code to extract a query into a csv file, but it duplicates the fields printed.

Is it something wrong with this code below?

```
if ( !$result1 ) { echo mysql_error(); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    fputcsv($fh, $result1, ',');
}
fclose($fh);
```

It all happened after i inserted `,` in fputcsv

Comment: $result1 is a result handle from mysql, it is **NOT** the row data you're fetching.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
fputcsv($fh, $result1, ',');
```

To:

```
fputcsv($fh, $row, ',');
```

**Update:** Although you refuse to provide more details, I'm guessing the problem after making this change is that `mysql_fetch_array` returns a combined numerically indexed/associative array by default.  You'll want to pass `MYSQL_NUM` to get the results you're after.  So the full code would be:

```
if (!$result1)
    echo mysql_error();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_NUM)) /* <-- Added MYSQL_NUM */
    fputcsv($fh, $row, ','); /* <-- $row, not $result1 */

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

```
fputcsv($fh, $result1, ',');
```

Don't you want this?

```
fputcsv($fh, $row, ',');
```